# How to label the Y axis with True, False and color code the Python plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, categories, anomaly-detection

I am trying to plot the `True` `False` values for data from a pandas series object `data3`. I want the `True` and `False` points to be color coded and the Y axis to indicate `True` and `False`.

I am already plotting the pandas series with `True` and `False` values which are automatically displayed as 1/0 in the following plot.

```py
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
   figure(num=None, figsize=(20,10), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
   plt.scatter(x = data3.index, y= data3, color='g', marker='d')
```

[image: Plot Results]

Including seaborn in the tag to see if there is a better option.

Comment: Maybe `plt.scatter(x = data3.index, y= data3, c=(data3 == True).astype(float), marker='d')`?

Comment: This solves the color coding. Is there a way to specify colors? The default colors seem too hard to see.

Comment: You could use a different colormap, define your own colormap, index custom colors... I'm pretty sure this has been asked and answered somewhere already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as clrs
figure(num=None, figsize=(20,10), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
cmap = clrs.ListedColormap(['red', 'green'])
plt.yticks([1.0, 0.0], ["True",
                        "False"])
plt.scatter(x = data3.index, y= data3, c=(data3 != True).astype(float), marker='d', cmap=cmap)#plt.cm.get_cmap('RdBu'))
```

This produces the following image

[image: CategoricalPlot]